# Java Program in course not working

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been following the java course http://www.programmingbydoing.com and I am stuck on one of the assignments could i get some help my code is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Si49CbN9

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );
    int age;
    String name;

    System.out.println( "What is your name" );
    name = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println( "So " + name + "how old are you? ")
    age = keyboard.nextInt();

    if ( age < 16 );
    {
        System.out.println( "You cant drive");
    }

    else ( age <= 17 );
    {
        System.out.println( "You can drive, but not vote." );
    }

    else ( age <= 24 );
    {
        System.out.println( "You can vote but not rent a car" );
    }

    else if
    {
        System.out.println( "You can do pretty much anything" );
    }
}
```

The assignments is:
Using if statements, else if, and else statements, make a program which displays a different message depending on the age given.

age message
less than 16    "You can't drive."
16 to 17    "You can drive but not vote."
18 to 24    "You can vote but not rent a car."
25 or older "You can do pretty much anything."

Note that unlike the original "How Old Are You" assignment, this program must only display exactly one message for a given age and not multiple messages.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: @JunedAhsan, the code was more-or-less posted by supplying a link to pastebin

Comment: This isnt for school or anything I am doing this on my own and this is one of the parts for the online course could you please help me :)

Comment: syntax is not correct

Comment: whenever i try to run in in cmd with the command javac HowOldAreYou2.java it shows 15 error messages

Comment: Your last "else if" you do not supply sufficent arguments for the if. Remove if or supply arguments. Also missing if before the statements in the other else statements.

Comment: Remember to remove semicolons from the end parantheses of your if-statements.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention the errors `javac` gave you. We can't / won't guess them.

Comment: Please learn to work in an IDE environment. Major examples for Java are Netbeans and Eclipse. This will make sure that you do not have to ask compiler errors (often) on sites like these.

Comment: @mthmulders  You are not alone in not wanting to make guesses, I am averse to guessing as well.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues

```
if ( age < 16 ) {   //SEE NO ; here. ; makes end of statement 
    System.out.println( "You cant drive");
}
else if( age <= 17 ) {
   //something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have swapped "else" and "else if" statements. The "else" statements should not take a condition the "else if" ones should. Also there is no ";" after the condition. I.e. it should be:

```
if (age < 16) {
...
} else if (age <= 17 ) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

Please try:

```
if ( age < 16 )
{
    System.out.println( "You cant drive");
}
else if ( age <= 17 )
{
    System.out.println( "You can drive, but not vote." );
}
else if ( age <= 24 )
{
    System.out.println( "You can vote but not rent a car" );
}
else 
{
    System.out.println( "You can do pretty much anything" );
}
```

You can learn if / then / else statement [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: I don't see why this answer is being downvoted, as it is the actual solution. Even thoug a proper explanation would be good to have.

Comment: @skiwi it initially had bogus semikolons - now it looks better

Comment: I was one of the downvoters, and I did so because its just the fish, not the fishing rod - in other words, it doesn't explain why or what was wrong. Downvoting is suggested for a situation where "This answer is not useful". Given the fact that the asker is following a Java course it is not useful to just say how it should be done without explaining anything.

Comment: @mthmulders i added some link below now.. hope asker can learn something.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if (age < 16){
        System.out.println( "You cant drive");
    } else if (age <= 17) {
        System.out.println( "You can drive, but not vote." );
    } else if (age <= 24) {
        System.out.println( "You can vote but not rent a car" );
    } else {
        System.out.println("You can do pretty much anything");
    }
```

Remove the semicolon in all the [if condition](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_decision_making.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(age>24) {
     {
            System.out.println( "You can do pretty much anything" );
        }

}
 if( age >= 17 && age<=24 )
{
    System.out.println( "You can vote but not rent a car" );
}

if( age <= 17 && age>=16 )
 {
System.out.println( "You can drive, but not vote." );
}
 if ( age<16 )
  {
     System.out.println( "You cant drive");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error.You can not append a condition statement to the keyword `else`.
Pls refer to below code:

```
if ( age < 16 )
    {
        System.out.println( "You cant drive");
    }

    else if( age <= 17 )
    {
        System.out.println( "You can drive, but not vote." );
    }

    else if ( age <= 24 )
    {
        System.out.println( "You can vote but not rent a car" );
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println( "You can do pretty much anything" );
    }
```